# How can I save the bounding box of a TikZpicture and use in other TikZpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I need 2 different TikZpictures with the same bounding box (the one of the first TikZpicture) because I need a perfect vertical alignment of the subfigures side by side.

Please, how can I handle this?

Comment: Note that it is unusual around here to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to have any greeting.

Comment: Related: [Centering a TikZ picture around an area](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/centering-a-tikz-picture-around-an-area).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `\useasboundingbox` command in the second picture to set the bounding box. Should be the first command in the picture.

```
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (<width of first picture>,<height of first picture>);
```

If you don't know the dimensions of the first picture you can get them from the `current bounding box` node. Using `remember picture` you can then access this information in the second node.

The code below will set the accept same bounding box for the second picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (-1,-1) -- (5,5);
   % more drawing commands ...
   \coordinate (FIRST NE) at (current bounding box.north east);
   \coordinate (FIRST SW) at (current bounding box.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\fbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \useasboundingbox (FIRST SW) rectangle (FIRST NE);
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

This works if both pictures use only positive coordinates. Adjustment must be made if this isn't the case.

The `\fbox` commands are only to display the bounding box and are not really required.

Comment: Now I know how to use pgf to avoid `\newbox` :) but you need to compile twice.

Comment: @Martin: The result is incorrect for me, the second line is out of the second box ?

Comment: @Altermundus: You don't need to compile it twice. It works fine in the first run. Maybe you are confusing `remember picture` with `overlay`?

Comment: @Altermundus (and Martin): It seems this solution only works correctly on the first compile. Compiling it again moves the short line down. Removing `[remember picture]` makes it work, though. Funny...

Comment: @Jake,Altermundus: I updated my example to the simple version I had before. It only works for positive coordinates, but shows that the principle works.

Comment: @Martin: The pgfmanual says "You need to use a driver that supports picture remembering and you need to run TeX twice". Like for Jake, the problem appears on the second run.

Comment: @Martin: Your new example doesn't work for me at all because you're referencing a coordinate `FIRST NE` that you didn't define in the first picture. Just removing `[remember picture]` from your previous solution works fine, negative coordinates and all!

Comment: Thanks all. Martin's solution shows the commands I was looking for. It works great in my code.

Comment: @Jake: Thanks twice. That error was a simple typo. Apparently I misunderstood the function of `remember picture`. Like you said it isn't required here, but actually hurts. The nodes seem to be defined global anyway!

Comment: @Jake:  you are right : `remember picture` is not necessary

Comment: @Martin: If you try `\draw (0,0) -- (11,11); ` in the second picture, the picture is greater than the bounding box ! so perhaps it's necessary to `clip` the rectangle.

Comment: @Altermundus: No, `\useasboundingbox` fixes the bounding box which wont change afterwards. However it's still possible to draw outside the boundaries. Then you might consider adding `clip`, but it wont have any influence on the alignment, which is the main concern of the OP.

Comment: @Martin: You are right. I corrected my comment before your last comment. The problem with a picture greater than the bounding box is to place other things around the pictures and to avoid surcharge but it's not the main concern of the OP, you are right.

Comment: @Fernando Nadal: Please do not forget to accept correct answers to all your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it is to use a single tikzpicture environment and one scope environment:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% TikZ code for first picture
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
% TikZ code for second picture
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then the points plotted at (x,y) in each scope will be exactly 5cm apart.

Answer (score 2):

The code of Martin is correct but if you want to know the width and the height of the picture, you can use

```
\newbox\mybox 
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Now you get the width and the height of picture with

```
\wd\mybox
\ht\mybox
\dp\mybox
```

The height is `\dp` + `\ht`. I don't know if pgf/TikZ gives the height and the width directly.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect vertical alignment of two independent `tikzpictures` can be obtained with a `tabular` with `m` columns (from `array` package) or with a `sidebyside` tcolorbox. Following code shows both options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array}
\newtcolorbox{mysidebyside}[1][]{%
enhanced, sidebyside,
sidebyside align= center seam,
halign = center, halign lower = center,
#1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mysidebyside}[]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--++(0:3cm)--++(60:3cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\tcblower
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--++(0:1cm)--++(60:1cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{mysidebyside}

\begin{mysidebyside}[empty]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--++(0:3cm)--++(60:3cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\tcblower
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--++(0:1cm)--++(60:1cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{mysidebyside}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.45\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.45\textwidth}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--++(0:3cm)--++(60:3cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--++(0:1cm)--++(60:1cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]