# Margins in \framebox

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, boxes, framed

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\framebox{\begin{tikzpicture}[color=black, line width=0.4mm]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (5mm,5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Result is

[image]

**The question is:** How to remove margins around the box in tikzpicture environment?

Comment: On second thought, this seems to be a duplicate of [TikZ add frame to a picture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12636/tikz-add-frame-to-a-picture).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use the `\frame` macro instead which draws a tight frame around it. For special content inside nodes, e.g. verbatim, I recommend the `\Frame` macro from my recent `realboxes` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\frame{\begin{tikzpicture}[color=black, line width=0.4mm]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (5mm,5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

`Tikz` provides you with the means to put a frame around your picture, even without a margin:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,inner frame sep=0mm]
\draw (0,0) ellipse (25mm and 15mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Refer to [the tikz manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), "25 Background Library" for further options

Comment: Thank you for answer. The problem was with using framebox. Nevertheless it is also useful to me as I had not known about such options of tikzpicture.

Answer (score 5):

The margins you are seeing are produced by two different reasons. First of all I guess that your input code was

```
\framebox{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[color=black, line width=0.4mm]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (5mm,5mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

that has two spurious spaces. Indeed, if the code is as shown in your message, the outer rectangle becomes a square. There's the parameter `\fboxsep` that stores the separation from the frame to the contents in a `\framebox`, its default value is 3pt. To get no separation you can write

```
\begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    <TikZ commands>;
    \end{tikxpicture}}\endgroup
```

so that the change to `\fboxsep` will hold only inside the group.

Comment: Now I understand the problem - I used wrong tools and got the wrong result. This solution works good, but solution with `\frame{}` is more elegant. Thank you for explanation.