# Tikz, centering object and correcting an arrow in flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf

i placed the circle with the word Start in the center of picture using positioning library:

```
\node[start] (start)  {start};
% row 2
\node[block] (measurement) [below of=start] {Add new measurement, \\ $y_k$ to buffer};
\node[left=6cm of measurement] (level three) {};
```

my question is if it possible to place Start circle in the center of the page in a more accurate way instead of guessing where the center is? (e.g. 0.5\textwidth)

my second question, i would like to correct line from *Number of regression* to *regression solution false and ...*. It should pass above the diamond and connect the diamond from the east side like the 3 other arrows.

**EDIT**

A solution to the array (vector) problem:

```
 \path [line,rounded corners] (i > 0 1.south) |- node[above right,midway] {$i=0$} ($(if 2.east) + (0.5,2)$) -- ($(if 2.east) + (0.5,0)$) -- (if 2.east);
```

simply creating an addition virtual point around *if 2* position, using ***calc*** library.

A solution for centering the *Start* circle i still havent found.

**END EDIT**
here is an example code i used:

```
  \documentclass[]{scrbook}

  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \selectlanguage{english}

  \usepackage[]{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
  \usepackage[landscape,a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{mathtools}

  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, shapes. geometric,calc,positioning}  

  \begin{document}
  \tikzset{decision/.style={diamond, aspect=2, draw, fill=blue!20, text badly centered, inner sep=0pt,align=center}}

  \tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text centered, rounded corners, align=center}}
  \tikzset{line/.style={draw, very thick, color=black!50, -latex'}}
  \tikzset{start/.style={shape=circle,draw,minimum size=1.2cm, draw=blue!80, fill=blue!20, text centered, align=center}}
  \tikzset{decision answer/.style={near start,color=black,auto}}
  \tikzset{datashape/.style={ trapezium, draw, trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=-60}}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm, auto, >=stealth, every node/.style={ auto, font=\footnotesize, anchor=center, >=stealth}]

% row 1
\node[start] (start)  {start};
% row 2
\node[block] (measurement) [below of=start] {Add new measurement, \\ $y_k$ to
buffer};
\node[left=6cm of measurement] (level three) {};
% row 3
\node[decision] (reg_status) [below left of=level three, node distance=3cm] %
{Regression\\status};%
\node[block] (update_goodness) [right of=reg_status,node distance=4cm] %
{update\\Goodness of Fit\\$\chi_\mathrm{red}^2$};%
\node [decision] (line_pass) [right of=update_goodness,node distance=4.5cm]%
{Is \\ $\left|\delta \right| < \left( 3.5\cdot \sigma_{\varepsilon} + %
\sigma_{\hat{\beta}_k}\right)$\\ and \\ $\chi_\mathrm{red}^2 < 1.6$};
\node [block] (update_beta_k) [right of=line_pass,node distance=5.5cm] %
{Update estimated values\\$\chi_\mathrm{red}^2$, $\hat{\beta}_k^i$ and %
$\operatorname{Cov}$};
% row 4
\node [block] (Reg_False) [below of=line_pass, node distance=2.3cm]%
{Set regression status\\equal False};
% row 5
\node [block] (create_replica) [right of=Reg_False,node distance=4cm]
{Create a replica of\\current regression solution\\$i \to i+1$};
\node [block] (Update_replica) [right of=create_replica,node distance=4cm]
{Clean buffer,\\Update:\\$\hat{\beta}_k^{i+1}$, $\operatorname{Cov}_k^{i+1}$ and %
$\chi_\mathrm{red}^2$};
% row 6
\node [decision] (i > 0 1) [below of=reg_status,node distance=4cm]
{Number\\of\\regression};
\node [block]    (update estimate) [right of=i > 0 1,node distance=5cm]
{Update estimated values \\ $^{i+1}\chi_\mathrm{red}^2$, $\hat{\beta}_k^{i+1}$ and %
$\operatorname{Cov}_k^{i+1}$};
% row 7 
\node [decision] (if 2) [below of=Update_replica,node distance=5cm]
{Is \\ regression solution false \\ and \\ sufficent number of measurements};

 \begin{scope}[every path/.style=line]
   \path [line] (start)-- (measurement);
   \path [line,rounded corners] (measurement) -| (reg_status);
   \path [line] (reg_status) -- node[above,midway] {True} (update_goodness);
   \path [line] (reg_status) -- node[near start,right] {False} (i > 0 1);
   \path [line] (update_goodness) -- (line_pass);
   \path [line] (line_pass) -- node[above,midway] {Yes} (update_beta_k);
   \path [line] (line_pass) -- node[right,midway] {No}  (Reg_False);
   \path [line] (Reg_False) -- (create_replica);
   \path [line] (create_replica) -- (Update_replica);
   \path [line] (i > 0 1) -- node[above,midway] {$i>0$} (update estimate);
   \path [line,rounded corners] (update_beta_k.east) -| ($(if 2.east) + (0.5,0)$) |- (if 2.east);
   \path [line,rounded corners] (Update_replica.east) -| ($(if 2.east) + (0.5,0)$) |- (if 2.east);
   \path [line,rounded corners] (update estimate.east) -| ($(if 2.east) + (0.5,0)$) |- (if 2.east);
   \path [line,rounded corners] (i > 0 1.south) |- node[above right,near start]%
            {$i=0$} ($(if 2.east) + (0.5,0)$) |- (if 2.east);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is a picture of what the above *TeX* code return

[image]

Comment: Have a look on the solutions for [Centering a TikZ picture around an area](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/centering-a-tikz-picture-around-an-area).

Comment: The problem of centring the start circle is that considered in the question that Martin links to above.  You should try the techniques given there.

Answer (score 2):

You can place `tikz` pictures exactly where you want on a page with the `current page` node, an absolute position with respect to a page. This is done with the following code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\draw[red] (current page.center) circle (1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want to place something exactly within a picture you may use the `current bounding box` node. With this approach, to center something horizontally on a page, you might consider

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
\draw (1,2) rectangle (4,4);

\draw[red] (current bounding box.north) circle (1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In your second example, the circle is placed in the middle of the page but has to be drawn _after_ the rest of the picture.  In particular, other pieces of the picture can't be drawn depending on its position (as they might adjust the bounding box and so move the circle out of the centre).