# pgfplots and figure centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pgfplots

I'm wondering about a way to exclude the axis labels and axis graduation from how latex will center the figure with respect to the caption. Labels and graduation along the y-axis (assuming it lies on the left of the figure) will tend to move the rest of the content to the right. I feel like it looks better when only the "main" content serves for centering purposes. Is such feature available?

Comment: The straight-forward and manual way would be use negative spacing (via `\hspace*{<hspace>}`). But I guess you want something more robust.

Comment: Related question: [Centering a TikZ picture around an area](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/centering-a-tikz-picture-around-an-area)

Comment: @Martin: I missed it. If I am correct, it is from May: is there something new?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `pgf` 2.10, you can provide the arguments `trim axis left` and `trim axis right` to the `tikzpicture` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
  \begin{axis}[ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel={$x$}]
    \addplot {x^2};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

(a)

\bigskip \bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture} % Example of leaving this out
  \begin{axis}[ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel={$x$}]
    \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

(a)

\end{document}
```

gives

[image: 2 graphs, of which the first is centred ignoring a very wide y axis title]

This works without disturbing the bounding box for the purposes of image externalisation and so forth (avoiding some of the problems discussed in @Martin's earlier question).

Comment: I've updated your code and image to more clearly highlight the experimental feature of `pgfplots`. The wide y-axis label distracted from the horizontal alignment, since there was no context (like a label `(a)`, say, that I've added). Feel free to rollback if this is unwanted. Good find on `trim left axis` and `trim right axis` though!

Comment: oh, I see - yes, this is a better way of demonstrating the centering than artificially broadening the y-axis label and needing to show the page margins. Thanks! Incidentally, although this is marked as experimental in the `pgfplots` manual, that refers to `pgf` 2.00: the relevant code has been incorporated into `pgf` 2.10 so it should be pretty generally usable, I think.

Comment: You're right - I was looking at an older version of the manual. Actually, much older than 2.00.

Comment: I've tried the provided code in a externalization setting, and the margins are not updated, meaning there is no centering. Is there something else that can be done then?