# TikZ: centre drawing at origin

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Centering a TikZ picture around an area](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/centering-a-tikz-picture-around-an-area)

I'm drawing 3 circles within each other with the same centre point, each circle represents a region for the project I'm doing. I've applied labels saying what each region is, but these labels is making the diagram appear off-centre with respect to the caption. I want the diagram to take the origin (0,0) as the centre (ie make it appear as though the labels have no effect on the position of the diagram in the figure) but have no idea how to do this.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw [color=red] (0,0) circle [radius=2];
\filldraw [color=Blue] (0,0) circle [radius=1.8];
\filldraw [color=Yellow] (0,0) circle [radius=1.4];
\draw [-,thin, black] (0,0) to [out=90,in=180] (3,1.5);
\node [right, black] at (3,1.5) {Label 1};
\draw [-,thin, black] (-1.6,0) to [out=90,in=0] (-3,1);
\node [left, black] at (-3,1) {Label 2};
\draw [-,thin, black] (1.9,0) to [out=90,in=180] (3,0.5);
\node [right, black] at (3,0.5) {Label 3};
\draw [color=black] (0,0) circle [radius=1.4];
\draw [color=black] (0,0) circle [radius=1.8];
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This looks like the same question as [Centering a TikZ picture around an area](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17463).

Comment: In this case it could be as easy as adding `use as bounding box` as an argument to the red circle, I think.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. that did exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: [x-post from /r/latex](http://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/16vqig/centring_at_origin_in_tikz/)