# How can I center a tikzpicture horizontally by a certain point/coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

this is a rather nit-picky question but I wanted to ask anyway. Is is possible to center the tikz figure horizontally with using the coordinate indicated by the red circle?

The catch is, I have found an answer already. Martin Scharrer provided a "good" compact snippet [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17578/25683). But considering my level of expertise and that I just copy and pasted some code I would like to make sure: is this a good practice still? Maybe some things inside TikZ changed in the last ~2 years and it now can be done easier?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
tgheros
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
    matrix,shapes.symbols,patterns,intersections,fit
    }

\tikzset{
    >=latex
}
\tikzset{xcenter around/.style 2 args={execute at end picture={%
  \useasboundingbox let \p0 = (current bounding box.south west), \p1 = (current bounding box.north east),
                        \p2 = (#1), \p3 = (#2)
                    in
        ({min(\x2 + \x3 - \x1,\x0)},\y0) rectangle ({max(\x3 + \x2 - \x0,\x1)},\y1);
}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,xcenter around = {0,0}{9,6}]
    %
    \draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (9.1,6.1);
    %
    \draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (9.5,0) node[anchor=west]{Employees}; %X-Achse
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[anchor=south]{Sales}; %Y-Achse
    %
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt);
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
    %
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} \draw (\x cm, 0 cm) node[anchor=north]{\x} coordinate (x axis);
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}  \draw (0 cm, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{\y} coordinate (y axis);
    %
    \node (orig) at (0,0) {};
    \draw
    (2,1) coordinate (A)
    (3,3) coordinate (B)
    (6.5,4.5) coordinate (C)
        (5,2) coordinate (D)
        (9,5) coordinate (E)
    ;
    %
    \foreach \pt/\labpos in {B/above left,C/below,D/below left}{
      \filldraw (\pt) circle (2pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
    };
    \foreach \pt/\labpos in {A/below,E/below}{
      \filldraw[gray] (\pt) circle (2pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
    };
    %
    \draw[draw=red,fill=red] (4.5,3) circle (4pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know if you will like it but replacing `\draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (9.5,0) node[anchor=west]{Employees};` with `\draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (9.5,0) node[below=4mm,midway]{Employees};` avoids your problem.

Comment: You can simply add `overlay` to the `Employees` node so that it doesn’t affect the bounding box (similar to how the `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment would do). Instead of `xcenter around` you can also add the `use as bounding box` option the the path with the `grid` (making the bounding box slightly larger than `xcenter around={0,0}{9,6}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks. Just to make sure: adding `use as bounding box` to the `grid` path would be additional to the `xcenter around` option?

Comment: @henry No, without `xcenter around`, although my solution of `use as bounding box` isn’t that different than using `xcenter around` only that you don't need to provide the points twice.

Comment: Please add you comment as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Just a note for other visitors: if `use as bounding` is used for the grid path and something (e.g. the graph's legend) is put above the grid, it might leak into the headline when the whole tikzpicture is inside a float environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the library fit to oversee all your scheme centering on the red dot and specifying a minimum width equal to the width of the page

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
tgheros
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
    matrix,shapes.symbols,patterns,intersections,fit
    }

\tikzset{
    >=latex
}
\tikzset{xcenter around/.style 2 args={execute at end picture={%
  \useasboundingbox let \p0 = (current bounding box.south west), \p1 = (current bounding box.north east),
                        \p2 = (#1), \p3 = (#2)
                    in
        ({min(\x2 + \x3 - \x1,\x0)},\y0) rectangle ({max(\x3 + \x2 - \x0,\x1)},\y1);
}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,xcenter around = {0,0}{9,6}]
    %
    \draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (9.1,6.1);
    %
    \draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (9.5,0) node[anchor=west](employees){Employees}; %X-Achse
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[anchor=south](sales){Sales}; %Y-Achse
    %
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt);
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
    %
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} \draw (\x cm, 0 cm) node[anchor=north]{\x} coordinate (x axis);
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}  \draw (0 cm, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{\y} coordinate (y axis);
    %
    \node (orig) at (0,0) {};
    \draw
    (2,1) coordinate (A)
    (3,3) coordinate (B)
    (6.5,4.5) coordinate (C)
        (5,2) coordinate (D)
        (9,5) coordinate (E)
    ;
    %
    \foreach \pt/\labpos in {B/above left,C/below,D/below left}{
      \filldraw (\pt) circle (2pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
    };
    \foreach \pt/\labpos in {A/below,E/below}{
      \filldraw[gray] (\pt) circle (2pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
    };
    %
    \draw[draw=red,fill=red] (4.5,3)coordinate(center) circle (4pt);

\node[fit=(center) (employees) (sales),minimum width=\linewidth,draw]at(center){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `rectangle` shape you used for the final `fit` includes the `outer xsep` in addition to `minimum width`. Notice the `overful \hbox` warning. Best thing would be to use `minimum width=\textwidth-2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep})` (or not using `draw` at all of course).

Comment: Ok, it's better

Comment: the draw, is only for the MWE