# White space creeping in when I place a tikz picture inside another tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

I'm trying to design a seating chart for my classroom.  I've done this using `pstricks`.  I wanted to try it in `tikz`.

What I'm doing is drawing a rectangle to represent each desk.  Since the desks are arranged into groups of four, I then group these four rectangles together.  The problem I'm having is when I try to group them together, I'm getting unexpected whitespace.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\mysmallbox}{%%"
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0,0) {};
    \node (B) at (6,4) {};
    \draw (A) rectangle (B);
    \draw (A.center|-B.center) -- (A.center-|B.center);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\boxesInboxes}{%%'
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (3,2) {\mysmallbox};
    \node (B) at (9,6) {\mysmallbox};
    \draw[color=red,line width=0.1pt] (0,0) rectangle (12,8);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\mysmallbox

\boxesInboxes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Where is the whitespace coming from?

**UPDATE**

I found [this solution about bounding boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57486/22413).  That seems far more complicated than I want.  Is there a simpler way of *pruning* the extra white space?

I also found [this solution about setting the bounding box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12474/22413), but I still get a little bit of white space in front of the picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `node` will have `inner sep`aration. Make it zero. Further, it is advisable to use `coordinate`s here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%\newcommand{\mysmallbox}{%%"
%  \begin{tikzpicture}
%    \node (A) at (0,0) {};
%    \node (B) at (6,4) {};
%    \draw (A) rectangle (B);
%    \draw (A.center|-B.center) -- (A.center-|B.center);
%  \end{tikzpicture}}


%% Use coordinate to see the difference
\newcommand{\mysmallbox}{%%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0) {};
    \coordinate (B) at (6,4) {};
    \draw (A) rectangle (B);
    \draw (A|-B) -- (A-|B);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\boxesInboxes}{%%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (A) at (3,2) {\mysmallbox};
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (B) at (9,6) {\mysmallbox};
    \draw[color=red,line width=0.1pt] (0,0) rectangle (12,8);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\mysmallbox

\boxesInboxes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That fixes things for my MWE.  But, I've still got a tiny bit of whitespace creeping in to my real document.  :*(  I'll see whether I can narrow it down some more and post an update in case I can't get rid of the space.

Comment: @A.Ellett Sure.

Comment: You could also kill the `outer sep`aration: `outer sep=0pt`.

Comment: This works perfectly.  I found where how my other white space was creeping in.  `inner sep=0pt` did the trick.