# How can I access the size of a tikzpicture's bounding box outside the tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to calculate the size of a tikzpicture using the current bounding box, but every time I try to extract the coordinates I get 0pt (for everything).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\mywidth}
\newlength{\myheight}

% computes width and height of tikzpicture

\newcommand{\pgfsize}[2]{ % #1 = width, #2 = height
 \pgfextractx{#1}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{south west}}
 {\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{north east}}}
 \pgfextracty{#2}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{south west}}
 {\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{north east}}}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw node[rotate=90]{
 \framebox{
 \begin{tabular}{c|c}
 first column & second column\\
 \hline
 1 & A\\
 2 & B\\
 $\vdots$ & $\vdots$
 \end{tabular}
}};
\draw[color=red] (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.north east);
\pgfsize{\mywidth}{\myheight}
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent
Width = \the\mywidth \\
Height = \the\myheight
\end{document}
```

As you can see, one can draw a line across the bounding box, so it exists and is non-trivial.  I'm thinking I may have to use \pgfgettransformentries, but when?

Comment: I think this issue is that you're setting `\mywidth` and `\myheight` locally, not globally.  So outside of the `tikzpicture`, they'll both be `0pt`.

Comment: Somehow related: [How can I save the bounding box of a TikZpicture and use in other TikZpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12473/how-can-i-save-the-bounding-box-of-a-tikzpicture-and-use-in-other-tikzpicture).  In particular [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12475/34258) seems relevant.

Comment: @anderstood - Actually, these days I just stick something is a savebox to measure it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[A. Ellet's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137356/calculate-size-of-tikzplot#comment310746_137356) is correct: it is a scope problem. Yes, `\mywidth` and `\myheight` are assigned a nonzero value within the scope of the `tikzpicture` environment, but, because those assignments are local, their value remains `0pt` outside the scope of that environment.

You can fix the problem by making the assignments of `\pgfsize`'s arguments global (rather than local) in the definition of that macro; see below. [This post by Andrew Swan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119738/21891) should also be of interest.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\show\pgfextractx

\newlength{\mywidth}
\newlength{\myheight}

% computes width and height of tikzpicture
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgfsize}[2]{ % #1 = width, #2 = height
 \pgfextractx{\@tempdima}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{south west}}
 {\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{north east}}}
 \global#1=\@tempdima
 \pgfextracty{\@tempdima}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{south west}}
 {\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{north east}}}
 \global#2=\@tempdima
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw node[rotate=90]{
 \framebox{
 \begin{tabular}{c|c}
 first column & second column\\
 \hline
 1 & A\\
 2 & B\\
 $\vdots$ & $\vdots$
 \end{tabular}
}};
\draw[color=red] (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.north east);
\pgfsize{\mywidth}{\myheight}
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent
Width = \the\mywidth \\
Height = \the\myheight
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand why juggling with `\mytemplength`. Just saying `\global#1=#1` is exactly the same. But I'd use a scratch register such as `\@tempdima`: `\pgfextractx{\@tempdima}{...}\global#1=\@tempdima` that avoids the bad practice of using both local and global assignments to a variable.

Comment: @egreg I used an intermediary variable because I though I would have trouble with recursion. Thanks for letting me know that my fears were unfounded. I'll improve my answer.

Comment: If you say `\let\mytemplength\mywidth` and `\mywidth` is allocated the skip register 43 (as in your example), doing `\show\mytemplength` will output `\mytemplength=\skip43` and you simply end up with `\global\skip43=\skip43`.

Comment: @egreg Why skip register 43? What is so special about 43?

Comment: When you say `\newlength\mywidth`, TeX allocates to `\mywidth` a skip register. It's 43 just because the last allocated skip register was number 42; but the number is of no concern for the end user: it may change if you load a new package, for instance; the important thing is that it's fixed during a run of (La)TeX. You find the allocated registers in the `.log` file.