# Express boxes properties in tikz coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, coordinates, baseline

In my understanding, any LaTeX box displays such fundamental properties:

[image]

.. and *anything* is wrapped into a LaTeX box.

So, when I produce a `tikz` picture, it must be somehow wrapped into a box. Indeed, it seems to display such a `height` and a `baseline` when I use it. For instance, this code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
  \tikzset{x=1pt, y=1pt, z=1pt}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mypicture}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (a) at (0, 0) {\strut$a$};
        \node (b) at (30, 0) {\strut$b$};
        \draw[->] (a) .. controls (15, -20) and (30, -30) .. (b);
\end{tikzpicture}}

In my rather long, multilined text, I wish I could insert \mypicture{} just
as if it were something natural..

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

.. now I think my point is getting clear. The above insertion does not seem natural at all since `\mypicture` box baseline does not match node `(a)` baseline. And if it would, vertical space between the two lines would probably be affected.

How to correct this without a dirty hand-tweak with `\raisebox`, `\vspace` *etc.*?

How to express all `tikz` pictures box properties in `tikz` coordinates?

Comment: You can use `[baseline, every node/.style={anchor=base}]` as options of your `tikzpicture`

Comment: @moospit this is nice, thanks. What about the other box properties like height and width? (see updated question)

Comment: @lago-lito from your question i read that your problem is the affection of the space between lines. I suggest the following ways to overcome this: 1) use another type of arrow or 2) use a `overlay` scope if the arrow may overlay other lines

Comment: This certainly is the problem one might read from my *example*, and your suggestion is a workaround dedicated to this case. My actual problem is to choose by myself properties of the box produced by `tikzpicture` environment like `height`, `width`, `baseline` and `depth` and to express them in `tikz` coordinates. For instance, what if I needed to recreate this *p* with `tikz` (adding, say, one horn) and make it behave correctly within natural text?

Comment: You could use the options `xscale` and `yscale` as options for your `tikzpicture`. As you set `x, y, z` to be 1pt this would be your base scaling. Doing it this way you could affect the scaling of all `tikz`-elements but *not* text. I don't believe that `tikz` is the best way to go when you want to create new characters (as your *p*)

Comment: Mmh, if I change scale, the arrow won't be the same anymore, right? Okay, I wouldn't create new characters with `tikz`. But how do I set `\mypicture`'s `height` to the `height` of `$b$`? How do I set its `depth` to the `depth` of `$a$`? How do I choose its `width` to be exactly, say, 40pt? I am aware that the drawing will then extend out of the box, but this is my intent.

Comment: I would have say `raisebox` and `resizebox` are the best options, but if I understand welll, you don't want to use them, and want to fix these values inside TikZ figure instead?

Comment: My problem is that using `raisebox` would involve manual tweaking of the graph, which is painful an not a robust solution anyway (what if I fancy adding a snowball on the top of *b*? It would break the tweak). In this sense, the `baseline` argument of `tikzpicture` is perfect. Concerning `resizebox`, I don't mind using it provided there is a way to tell it "let your `height` be the `height` of node `(b)`" or "let your `width` be the `width` of the arrow, so adapt this `width` whenever I fancy changing the control points" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution I needed was a combination of both `baseline` and the wonderful key `use as bounding box`: consider this :)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \tikzset{x=1pt, y=1pt, z=1pt}

\begin{document}

\def\myfig{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(base)] % choose baseline
    % box dimensions
    \path[draw, use as bounding box] (0, 0) rectangle (10, 15);
    % set baseline
    \coordinate (base) at (0, 5);
    % actual content
    \path[fill=blue] (0, 0) % a random path
        ..  controls (10, 10)
                 and (10, -10) ..
                     (10, 20) -- cycle;
    % visualize baseline
    \draw (0, 5) -- (10, 5);
\end{tikzpicture}}

Now I can define \emph{every} frea\myfig ng property of my tikz box!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Phew!

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you will have to tell TikZ where you want your `baseline` to be. Here you want it to be for example on your `(a)` node.

Here is a code to provide it :

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
  \tikzset{x=1pt, y=1pt, z=1pt}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mypicture}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base)]
        \node (a) at (0, 0) {\strut$a$};
        \node (b) at (30, 0) {\strut$b$};
        \draw[->] (a) .. controls (15, 20) and (30, 30) .. (b);
\end{tikzpicture}}

In my text, insert \mypicture{} just as if it were something natural..


\end{document}
```

And its result :

[image]

I hope it may help.

Comment: This does help, thanks :) What about the other box properties like height and width? (see updated question)

Comment: To obtain TikZ figure `height` and `width`, I think this post may be usefull http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137356/how-can-i-access-the-size-of-a-tikzpictures-bounding-box-outside-the-tikzpictur.

Comment: I am not sure how this would help. I need to somehow *constrain* properties of the figure box, what would I use their spontaneous `height` and `width` for?

Comment: What do you mean by constraining the box? Autoscaling?

Comment: Regarding again the question, you told that you didn't want to dirty hand-tweak with `\raisebox`. But, may I suggest a `\raisebox` with `depth` set to zero, and `\height` automatic, this used with a `node.baseline` as in my answer. For the use of `\raisebox`, I suggest something like `\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{\mypicture}`.
It produces a correct input for you baseline, and avoid having big line skip. However, you will face text overlaping the picture sometimes. If you want, I may update my answer.