# Trimming trailing space in tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have defined several `tikz` figures into custom `\myfig` commands, which I
need to place and rescale within other figures. This simple task is getting
*really* difficult because, for some reason, `tikz` boxes and nodes are not
trimmed right.

I do not understand the general functionning of margins and trailing spaces in
with `tikz` pictures: why is there so much white space underneath this random
blue path for example?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \tikzset{x=1pt, y=1pt, z=1pt}

\begin{document}

Why

% a reusable figure
\def\myfig{\begin{tikzpicture}
        [inner sep=0, outer sep=0] % just in case
    \path[fill=blue] (0, 0) % a random path
        ..  controls (10, 10)
                 and (10, -10) ..
                     (20, 20) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}}

% an actual figure
in \begin{tikzpicture}
    [inner sep=0, outer sep=0] % just in case
    \node
        [draw, inner sep=0, outer sep=0] % just in case
        () at (0, 0) {\resizebox{20pt}{!}{\myfig}};
\end{tikzpicture} the

\LaTeX?

\end{document}
```

[image]

.. and how may I remove it?

I have the feeling that this closely relates to [this
question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295626/) which has still not
been answered yet.

**[EDIT]**
It *has* been answered now, so that I can solve my problem in a more general way using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302235/72679) :)

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clip your figure. As it is, their (invisible) points for curve design with `.. controls ..` are far below of visible shape.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \tikzset{x=1pt, y=1pt, z=1pt}

\begin{document}
Why

% a reusable figure
\def\myfig{\begin{tikzpicture}
        [inner sep=0, outer sep=0] % just in case
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (20,20);% <--- added
    \path[fill=blue] ( 0,  0) % a random path
        ..  controls (10, 10)
                 and (10,-10) ..
                     (20, 20) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}}

% an actual figure
in \begin{tikzpicture}
    [inner sep=0, outer sep=0] % just in case
    \node
        [draw, inner sep=0, outer sep=0] % just in case
        at (0, 0) {\myfig};
\end{tikzpicture} the

\LaTeX?
\end{document}
```

Comment: GREAT ! So the control points were the actual problem. They are invisible so they were driving me mad ^ ^ Cheers :)