# How to get "inner" auto-positionning of a TikzPicture legend?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, legend

## EDIT 2 (Feb 20): New question (hopefully clearer)

With `pgfplots` it's possible to obtain "inner" and "outer" figure legend (see [Paul Gessler's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227101/262081)) as:

[image]

I would like to achieve the same result with a "simple" Tikz picture (*i.e.* not a plot).

Currently, thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/532088/262081) or John Kormylo's anwser [below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634513/262081), I am able to create a legend with a Tikzpicture positionned with `current bounding box.south east` (see MWE at the end):

[image]

So, positionning with `current bounding box.south east` is equivalent to the "outer" positionning with `pgfplots`.

**How can I achieve the equivalent to the "inner" positionning with the legend in the previous figure** and without using an absolute shift (*i.e.* `[yshift=.., xshift=..]`) but using something like `pos=`**`inner`** `current bounding box.south east` instead?

I specify that the way the legend is built in my MWE is not limiting, that is to say that I am open to other ways of creating a legend (with `scope`, `path`,...) if that makes "inner" positioning possible.

## EDIT 3 (Feb 24): First attempt

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer comment below, I get this (which is very closed to my needs):

[image]

The last problem is a legend overlap with the node. I wonder if I can detect or access to the `legend` node height in order to plot the `legend` node with a `yshift` equal to its height (because the legend could be a multiline matrix).

Thanks to [percusse answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410989/262081) I'm able to obtain this:

[image]

Where, the "bleu legend" is the final result I would like to obtain. The "black legend" was used only to determine the `legend` node height and I would like to delete it...
The red text and line show the lenght of the `yshit` stored in `\mytemp` and corresponding to the `legend` node height.

**How can I remove the black legend after determining its height?**

**Or any other idea to automatically set the `yshift` in order to avoid overlaping?**

And the MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz=true,crop=true,class=minimal,border=1pt,10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=localbox]
% NODES
\node (n1)  [draw, text width=5em, minimum height=8em]   {node 1};%
% ARROWS
\coordinate[above right=of n1.east] (aux2a);
\coordinate[below right=of n1.east] (aux2b);
%
\draw[-latex]  (aux2a -| n1.east) 
    to (aux2a) node[right] {short label};
\draw[-latex]  (aux2b -| n1.east) 
    to (aux2b) node[right] {a bit longer label};
\end{scope}   
% LEGEND
% First black Legend
 \path (localbox.north west)%
 node[name=legend,matrix,anchor=west,cells={nodes={font=\sffamily,anchor=west}},
 draw,thick,inner sep=0.3ex]{%
  \draw[-latex](0,0) -- ++ (0.6,0); & \node{arrow};\\
 };%

% Access to black legend node height
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{legend}{south west}}{\pgfpointanchor{legend}{north west}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\mytemp{\csname pgf@y\endcsname}
\draw[red] ([xshift=1mm]legend.north east) -- ++(0pt,\mytemp pt) 
                                                         node[midway,right] {\mytemp pt};
% Final blue legend                                              
 \path ([yshift=\mytemp pt]localbox.north west)%
  node[name=legend,matrix,anchor=west,cells={nodes={font=\sffamily,anchor=west}},
 draw,thick,inner sep=0.3ex,draw=blue!80]{%
  \draw[-latex](0,0) -- ++ (0.6,0); & \node{arrow};\\
 };% 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Old question (unclear)

Thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/532088/262081) I am able to plot a legend like this with a Tikzpicture (the legend is in the bottom right corner in the figure below, placed with `\path(current bounding box.south east)`, see MWE at the end):

[image]

But I would prefer this result (warning: red things are not wanted in the final result, it is just for explanation purpose):

[image]

**Start EDIT 1.1** In other words, I would like to place the legend with something equivalent to `(current bounding box.south east)` but not starting relatively from the `south east` of the `bounding box` but from the `south east` "inside of the picture borders" instead (green coordinates in the following figure). (BTW I'm not sure the red lines reflect the real behaviour and coordinates when unsing `(current bounding box.south east)`)

[image]

**End EDIT 1.1**

Another exemple of expected result would be, with a bigger node:

[image]

Or this (with something like `north east`):

[image]

- Is there a way to obtain this behaviour automatically by using someting like `(current` "`limits`" `box.south east)`?
- If yes, it is also possible to choose the minimal vertical distance represented by the `ymin` in the figure above (which could take negative values): `\path([ymin=-5mm]current limits box.south east)`?
- If yes, it is also possible to choose also a minimal horizontal distance `xmin` like this:

[image]

## The MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz=true,crop=true,class=minimal,border=1pt,10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% NODES
\node (n1)  [draw, text width=5em, minimum height=8em]   {node 1};%
% ARROWS
\coordinate[above right=of n1.east] (aux2a);
\coordinate[below right=of n1.east] (aux2b);
%
\draw[-latex]  (aux2a -| n1.east) 
    to (aux2a) node[right] {short label};
\draw[-latex]  (aux2b -| n1.east) 
    to (aux2b) node[right] {a bit longer label};
% LEGEND
 \path (current bounding box.south east)%
 node[matrix,anchor=north west,cells={nodes={font=\sffamily,anchor=west}},
 draw,thick,inner sep=0.3ex]{%
  \draw[-latex](0,0) -- ++ (0.6,0); & \node{arrow};\\
 };%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Start EDIT 1.2** **Why I want that?**

Auto-positionning of the legend "inside the image limits" would allow very fast positionning with compact picture by just giving a `ymin` in order to be sure to not overlap anything with the legend.

This "clever" behaviour would allow the possibility to better automate the picture generation by adding the legend automaticaly and set, for e.g. `ymin=1mm` and `xmin=1mm` to prevent any overlaping problem.

**End EDIT 1.2**

Comment: You can create a [local bounding box=name] with a scope.  It will have all the usual anchors.

Comment: @John Thanks. What do you mean by "with a scope"?

Comment: While you don't **have** to do it this way, I have always used `\begin{scope}[local bounding box=name] ... \end{scope}` to create named boxes.

Comment: @John Ok, I tried some things but I don't know how to place the `scope` in the picture. In order to be sure I well understand your comment, your are proposing to use `\begin{scope}[local bounding box=name] ... \end{scope}` instead of `\path (current bounding box.south east)...` for the legend "block" only right?

Comment: it doesn't make sense to think in "inner" and "outer" concepts. Nodes are placed by putting one of their anchors at a certain coordinate. If you want the node to be below and left of `(current bounding box.south east)` use `anchor=north east`.

Comment: @Ulrike Fisher Thanks for the clarifications. Thanks to your comment I get something promising (at least I hope): cf. my third edit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You lost me on the "legend" construction.  See [Using a pgfplots-style legend in a plain-old tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture) for alternatives.

You can also use `\begin{scope}[shift=(fred.south east)] ...\end{scope}` to position another scope relative to the local bounding box (fred).

```
\documentclass[tikz=true,crop=true,class=minimal,border=1pt,10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=fred]
% NODES
\node (n1)  [draw, text width=5em, minimum height=8em]   {node 1};%
% ARROWS
\coordinate[above right=of n1.east] (aux2a);
\coordinate[below right=of n1.east] (aux2b);
%
\draw[-latex]  (aux2a -| n1.east) 
    to (aux2a) node[right] {short label};
\draw[-latex]  (aux2b -| n1.east) 
    to (aux2b) node[right] {a bit longer label};
\end{scope}
% LEGEND
 \path (fred.south east)%
 node[matrix,anchor=north west,cells={nodes={font=\sffamily,anchor=west}},
 draw,thick,inner sep=0.3ex]{%
  \draw[-latex](0,0) -- ++ (0.6,0); & \node{arrow};\\
 };%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and comments. I like this way of doing using scopes, thanks for that. Unfortunetly, it gives exactly the same results as in my MWE...

Comment: So basically you wan to apply a shift?  With the calc tikzlibrary one can use `($(fred.south east) + (xshift,yshift)$)`.  Or you could define a new location using `\path (fred.south east) ++ (xshift,yshift) coordinate (wilma);`

Comment: Ok my question is still unclear sorry. I made a second edit...

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you try to do. Maybe the following can be of use!?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\ymin}{-5mm}
\newcommand{\xmin}{0mm}
% NODES
\node (n1)  [draw, text width=5em, minimum height=8em]   {node 1};%
% ARROWS
\coordinate[above right=of n1.east] (aux2a);
\coordinate[below right=of n1.east] (aux2b);
%
\draw[-latex]  (aux2a -| n1.east) 
    to (aux2a) node[right] {short label};
\draw[-latex]  (aux2b -| n1.east) 
    to (aux2b) node[right, inner sep=0] (n) {a bit longer label};
% LEGEND
 \path ([yshift=\ymin, xshift=\xmin]current bounding box.south east)%
 node[matrix,anchor=north west,cells={nodes={font=\sffamily,anchor=west}},
 draw,thick,inner sep=0.3ex]{%
  \draw[-latex](0,0) -- ++ (0.6,0); & \node{arrow};\\
 };%
 \draw[red, dashed] (n.south east) -- +(0,3)  -- +(0,-2);
\draw[red, dashed] (n1.south west) -| (n.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rectangle node with arrows]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution was already proposed in the linked [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/532088/262081) and here I would like something more clever... It make me realise that my question was unclear. Indeed, I wonder if it could be possible to have an equivalent to `([yshift=\ymin, xshift=\xmin]current bounding box.south east)` but NOT starting from the `south east of the bouding box` but from the `south east` of the "picture borders" (see EDIT 1.1 and 1.2 of my question for more details). Thanks again anyway!

Answer (score 0):

> This answer is here in order to not let this question without an almost "working" answer, if someone (by the greatest of chance) comes across this solution and wishes (strangely) to use it.

Here is the ugly solution I finally used, presented in two ways: manual method and method using a new environment.

Both methods use the legend anchor to achieve the right "inner" positioning (thanks to Ulrike Fischer's comment).

## Manual solution

- If there is **NO** overlapping, the legend is just polted with (using a scope: `local bounding box=localbox`) `\path (localbox.south east)  node[name=legend,anchor=`**`west`**`...` [image]
- If there is overlapping (the legend is shifted reagarding to it's own size):

1. First, a temporary legend node is plotted at (0,0) coodinate: [image]
2. Second, the size (widht and height) of this legend is extracted (thanks to [percusse's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410989/262081)).
3. Third, the temporary legend is entirely hide by a white rectangle: `\node (whiterec) [rectangle,fill=white,draw=white,minimum height=`**`\legendheight`** `pt,minimum width=`**`\legendwidth`** `pt] at (legend){};`
4. Fourth, the content of the Tikzpicture is plotted.
5. Fifth, the final legend is plotted and shifted regarding the size of the remporary legend (here an exemple at north west): [image]

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz=true,crop=true,class=minimal,border=1pt,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=localbox]
% First temporary black Legend
 \path (0,0)%
node[name=legend,matrix,anchor=west,cells={nodes={font=\sffamily,anchor=west}},
 draw,thick,inner sep=0.3ex]{%
  \draw[-latex](0,0) -- ++ (0.6,0); & \node{arrow};\\
 };%
% Access to black legend node height and width
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{legend}{south west}}{\pgfpointanchor{legend}{north west}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\legendheight{\csname pgf@y\endcsname}                                                                                         
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{legend}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{legend}{east}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\legendwidth{\csname pgf@x\endcsname}%
% NODES
\node (whiterec) [rectangle,fill=white,draw=white,minimum height=\legendheight pt,minimum width=\legendwidth pt] at (legend){};
\node (n1)  [draw, text width=5em, minimum height=8em]   {node 1};%
% ARROWS
\coordinate[above right=of n1.east] (aux2a);
\coordinate[below right=of n1.east] (aux2b);
%
\draw[-latex]  (aux2a -| n1.east) 
    to (aux2a) node[right] {short label};
\draw[-latex]  (aux2b -| n1.east) 
    to (aux2b) node[right] {a bit longer label};:
% LEGEND
% Final blue legend                                              
 \path ([yshift=\legendheight/2 pt+1pt]localbox.north west)%
  node[name=legend,matrix,anchor=west,cells={nodes={font=\sffamily,anchor=west}},
 draw,thick,inner sep=0.3ex,draw=blue!80]{%
  \draw[-latex](0,0) -- ++ (0.6,0); & \node{arrow};\\
 };% 
\end{scope}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Method using a new environment

This method uses a new `tikzpictureWithInnerLegend` environment wich act as a `tikzpicture` environment but automaticaly draw the temporary legend, get its size and plot the final legend (in the same way as the Manual Method above).

1. First the style of the Final an temporary legends are defined, e.g.:

```
\tikzstyle{legend}=[name=legend,matrix,cells={nodes={font=\sffamily,anchor=west}},
 draw,thick,inner sep=0.3ex,draw=blue!80]%
\tikzstyle{templegend}=[name=templegend,matrix,cells={nodes={font=\sffamily,anchor=west}},
 draw,thick,inner sep=0.3ex,draw=white,fill=white]%
```

2. The legend content is stored into a macro, e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\legendcontent}{%
\draw[-latex](0,0) -- ++ (0.6,0); \& \node{arrow};\\% Be carefful to put \& instead of &
\draw[-stealth](0,0) -- ++ (0.6,0); \& \node{arrow2};\\% Be carefful to put \& instead of &
}%
```

3. The enviroment is called, e.g. with a lengend at `current bounding box.south east`:

```
\begin{tikzpictureWithInnerLegend}{\legendcontent}{current bounding box.south east}[xshift=\xmin, yshift=\ymin, autoshiftsign=true]
% NODES
\node (n1)  [draw, text width=5em, minimum height=8em]  {node};%
% ARROWS
\coordinate[above right=of n1.east] (aux2a);
\coordinate[below right=of n1.east] (aux2b);
%
\draw[-latex]  (aux2a -| n1.east) 
    to (aux2a) node[right] {short label};
\draw[-stealth]  (aux2b -| n1.east) 
    to (aux2b) node[right] {a bit longer label};:
\end{tikzpictureWithInnerLegend}
```

[image]

4. The environment options are as follows:

- `[xshift=\xmin, yshift=\ymin]`: apply respectively a `xshift` and a `yshift` to the final legend positioning.
- `[autoshiftsign=true]`: automatically change the sign of the `xshift` and `yshift` in order to avoid legend overlapping. Default value is `false` even if you just write `[autoshiftsign]` (i.e. the signs are directly given with the `xshift` and `yshift` options, e.g.: `xshift=-3pt`).

### Limitations and possible improvements

1. The code could be greatly improved in order to be more readable and efficient, e.g. many things are written identically in several places (in the start environment code with or without optional argument for example), as is the case with the `\pgfkeys` macro.
2. The use of `listofitems` package could probably be avoided. This package is only used in order to split the legend location given by the user, e.g. in `current bounding box.south east` the key `east` is extracted in oder to set the legend anchor. Also, it permits to make the difference between `current bounding box.south east` and `current bounding box.south`.

### Whole (ugly) code:

```
\documentclass[tikz=true,crop=true,class=minimal,border=1pt,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,matrix}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{xparse}


\NewDocumentEnvironment{tikzpictureWithInnerLegend}{m m o}%
{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
% # Start code if no opt arg
%-----------------------------------------------------------
% ## Initialization
\pgfkeys{
 /tikzpictureWithInnerLegend/.is family, /tikzpictureWithInnerLegend/.cd, %<-added /.cd 
 autoshiftsign/.is choice,
 autoshiftsign/.default=false,
 autoshiftsign/true/.code={\renewcommand{\autoShiftSignBool}{1}},
 autoshiftsign/false/.code={\renewcommand{\autoShiftSignBool}{0}},
 xshift/.estore in ={\xShift},
 yshift/.estore in ={\yShift},
} 
\newcommand*{\pathLocation}{}
\newcommand*{\lgdAnchor}{}
\newcommand{\xshiftSign}{0}
\newcommand{\yshiftSign}{0}
\newcommand{\xShift}{0}
\newcommand{\yShift}{0}
\newcommand{\xAutoShiftBool}{0}
\newcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{0}
\newcommand{\autoShiftSignBool}{0}
\def\zero{0}%
\def\plus{+}%
\def\minus{-}%
\def\north{north}%
\def\south{south}%
\def\east{east}%
\def\west{west}%
% ## Main Start Code
\ignoreemptyitems% Ingnore empty items from the list
\setsepchar{.}%
\readlist\mylist{#2}%
\setsepchar{ }%
\itemtomacro\mylist[2]\mylistmacro
\readlist\mysublist{\mylistmacro}%
\itemtomacro\mysublist[1]\cardinal
\if\mysublistlen2
  \renewcommand*{\pathLocation}{\mylist[1].\mysublist[1] \mysublist[2]}%
  \renewcommand*{\lgdAnchor}{\mysublist[2]}%
    \ifx\north\cardinal
        \renewcommand{\yshiftSign}{+}%
        \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{1}%
    \else 
            \ifx\south\cardinal
            \renewcommand{\yshiftSign}{-}%
            \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{1}%
         \else
            \renewcommand{\yshiftSign}{+}%
            \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{0}%
            \ifx\east\cardinal
                    \renewcommand{\xshiftSign}{+}%
                    \renewcommand{\xAutoShiftBool}{1}%
            \else
                    \renewcommand{\xshiftSign}{-}%
                    \renewcommand{\xAutoShiftBool}{1}%   
             \fi
         \fi
   \fi
\else
  \renewcommand*{\pathLocation}{\mylist[1].\mysublist[1]}%
  \renewcommand*{\lgdAnchor}{\mysublist[1]}%
    \ifx\north\cardinal
        \renewcommand{\yshiftSign}{+}%
        \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{1}%
        \renewcommand*{\lgdAnchor}{center}%
    \else 
            \ifx\south\cardinal
            \renewcommand{\yshiftSign}{-}%
            \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{1}%
            \renewcommand*{\lgdAnchor}{center}%
         \else
            \renewcommand{\yshiftSign}{+}%
            \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{0}%
            \ifx\east\cardinal
                    \renewcommand{\xshiftSign}{+}%
                    \renewcommand{\xAutoShiftBool}{1}%
            \else
                    \renewcommand{\xshiftSign}{-}%
                    \renewcommand{\xAutoShiftBool}{1}%    
             \fi
         \fi
   \fi
\fi
\begin{tikzpicture} [ampersand replacement=\&]
% ### Print temporary legend node
 \path (0,0)%
node[templegend]{#1};%
% ### Access to temporary legend node height and width
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{templegend}{south west}}{\pgfpointanchor{templegend}{north west}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\legendheight{\csname pgf@y\endcsname}                                                                                         
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{templegend}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{templegend}{east}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\legendwidth{\csname pgf@x\endcsname}%
\node (whiterec) [rectangle,fill=white,draw=white,minimum height=\legendheight pt,minimum width=\legendwidth pt] at (templegend){};
}%
{%
% # Start code if opt arg
%-----------------------------------------------------------
% ## Initialization
\pgfkeys{
 /tikzpictureWithInnerLegend/.is family, /tikzpictureWithInnerLegend/.cd, %<-added /.cd 
 autoshiftsign/.is choice,
 autoshiftsign/.default=false,
 autoshiftsign/true/.code={\renewcommand{\autoShiftSignBool}{1}},
 autoshiftsign/false/.code={\renewcommand{\autoShiftSignBool}{0}},
 xshift/.estore in ={\xShift},
 yshift/.estore in ={\yShift},
} 
\newcommand*{\pathLocation}{}
\newcommand*{\lgdAnchor}{}
\newcommand{\xshiftSign}{0}
\newcommand{\yshiftSign}{0}
\newcommand{\xShift}{0}
\newcommand{\yShift}{0}
\newcommand{\xAutoShiftBool}{0}
\newcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{0}
\newcommand{\autoShiftSignBool}{0}
\def\zero{0}%
\def\plus{+}%
\def\minus{-}%
\def\north{north}%
\def\south{south}%
\def\east{east}%
\def\west{west}%
% ## Main Start Code
\pgfkeys{/tikzpictureWithInnerLegend,#3}%
\ifx\minus\xshiftSign
    \renewcommand{\xAutoShiftBool}{1}%
\else
    \ifx\plus\xshiftSign
            \renewcommand{\xAutoShiftBool}{1}%
    \else
    \renewcommand{\xAutoShiftBool}{0}%
    \fi
\fi
\ifx\minus\yshiftSign
    \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{1}%
\else
    \ifx\plus\yshiftSign
            \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{1}%
    \else
    \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{0}%
    \fi
\fi
\ignoreemptyitems% Ingnore empty items from the list
\setsepchar{.}%
\readlist\mylist{#2}%
\setsepchar{ }%
\itemtomacro\mylist[2]\mylistmacro
\readlist\mysublist{\mylistmacro}%
\itemtomacro\mysublist[1]\cardinal
\if\mysublistlen2
  \renewcommand*{\pathLocation}{\mylist[1].\mysublist[1] \mysublist[2]}%
  \renewcommand*{\lgdAnchor}{\mysublist[2]}%
    \ifx\north\cardinal
        \renewcommand{\yshiftSign}{+}%
        \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{1}%
    \else 
            \ifx\south\cardinal
            \renewcommand{\yshiftSign}{-}%
            \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{1}%
         \else
            \renewcommand{\yshiftSign}{+}%
            \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{0}%
            \ifx\east\cardinal
                    \renewcommand{\xshiftSign}{+}%
                    \renewcommand{\xAutoShiftBool}{1}%
            \else           
                    \renewcommand{\xshiftSign}{-}%
                    \renewcommand{\xAutoShiftBool}{1}%
             \fi
         \fi
\fi
\else
  \renewcommand*{\pathLocation}{\mylist[1].\mysublist[1]}%
  \renewcommand*{\lgdAnchor}{\mysublist[1]}%
    \ifx\north\cardinal
        \renewcommand{\yshiftSign}{+}%
        \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{1}%
        \renewcommand*{\lgdAnchor}{center}%
    \else 
            \ifx\south\cardinal
            \renewcommand{\yshiftSign}{-}%
            \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{1}%
            \renewcommand*{\lgdAnchor}{center}%
         \else
            \renewcommand{\yshiftSign}{+}%
            \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{0}%
            \ifx\east\cardinal
                    \renewcommand{\xshiftSign}{+}%
                    \renewcommand{\xAutoShiftBool}{1}%
            \else
                    \ifx\west\cardinal
                        \renewcommand{\xshiftSign}{-}%
                        \renewcommand{\xAutoShiftBool}{1}%
                \else% Center
                        \renewcommand{\xshiftSign}{+}%
                        \renewcommand{\yshiftSign}{+}%
                        \renewcommand{\xAutoShiftBool}{0}%  
                        \renewcommand{\yAutoShiftBool}{0}% 
                        \renewcommand*{\lgdAnchor}{center}%
                \fi     
             \fi
         \fi
\fi
\fi
\begin{tikzpicture} [ampersand replacement=\&]%
% ### Print temporary legend node
 \path (0,0)%
node[templegend]{#1};%
% ### Access to temporary legend node height and width
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{templegend}{south west}}{\pgfpointanchor{templegend}{north west}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\legendheight{\csname pgf@y\endcsname}%                                                                                         
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{templegend}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{templegend}{east}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\legendwidth{\csname pgf@x\endcsname}%
\node (whiterec) [rectangle,fill=white,draw=white,minimum height=\legendheight pt,minimum width=\legendwidth pt] at (templegend){};%
}}%
{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
% # End code if no opt arg
%-----------------------------------------------------------
% ## LEGEND                                             
\path ([xshift=\xAutoShiftBool*\legendwidth*\xshiftSign1 pt+\autoShiftSignBool*\xShift*\xshiftSign1+(1-\autoShiftSignBool)*\xShift,yshift=\yAutoShiftBool*\legendheight/2*\yshiftSign1 pt+\autoShiftSignBool*\yShift*\yshiftSign1+(1-\autoShiftSignBool)*\yShift]#2)%
node[legend,anchor=\lgdAnchor]{#1};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
{%
% # End code if opt arg
%-----------------------------------------------------------
% ## LEGEND                                             
\path ([xshift=\xAutoShiftBool*\legendwidth*\xshiftSign1 pt+\autoShiftSignBool*\xShift*\xshiftSign1+(1-\autoShiftSignBool)*\xShift,yshift=\yAutoShiftBool*\legendheight/2*\yshiftSign1 pt+\autoShiftSignBool*\yShift*\yshiftSign1+(1-\autoShiftSignBool)*\yShift]#2)%
node[legend,anchor=\lgdAnchor]{#1};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}}%



\begin{document}
% Legend Formating
\tikzstyle{legend}=[name=legend,matrix,cells={nodes={font=\sffamily,anchor=west}},
 draw,thick,inner sep=0.3ex,draw=blue!80]%
\tikzstyle{templegend}=[name=templegend,matrix,cells={nodes={font=\sffamily,anchor=west}},
 draw,thick,inner sep=0.3ex,draw=white,fill=white]%
% Legend Content
\newcommand{\legendcontent}{%
\draw[-latex](0,0) -- ++ (0.6,0); \& \node{arrow};\\% Be carefful to put \& instead of &
\draw[-stealth](0,0) -- ++ (0.6,0); \& \node{arrow2};\\% Be carefful to put \& instead of &
}%
% Legend manual shift
\newcommand{\xmin}{0pt}% Minimal xshift to avoid ovelapping
\newcommand{\ymin}{1pt}% Minimal yshift to avoid ovelapping

\begin{tikzpictureWithInnerLegend}{\legendcontent}{current bounding box.south east}[xshift=\xmin, yshift=\ymin, autoshiftsign=true]
% NODES
\node (n1)  [draw, text width=5em, minimum height=8em]  {node};%
% ARROWS
\coordinate[above right=of n1.east] (aux2a);
\coordinate[below right=of n1.east] (aux2b);
%
\draw[-latex]  (aux2a -| n1.east) 
    to (aux2a) node[right] {short label};
\draw[-stealth]  (aux2b -| n1.east) 
    to (aux2b) node[right] {a bit longer label};:
\end{tikzpictureWithInnerLegend}

\end{document}
```