# Align tikzpictures at internal bounding box with text below it

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, bounding-box

I want to align the bottom of the red bounding boxes, but can't seem to find the right combination of `baseline` and `anchor` options to get this to work.

The failing test case of the MWE below is the case where the number of lines in the text differs from the two `tikzpicture`s:

[image]

### Notes:

- Ideally I would prefer to add code only to the `\DrawBoundingBox` if at all possible.

### References:

- [How to align a series of TikZ pictures at the baseline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58281/4301)
- [Anchoring TiKZ pics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185279/4301)
- [Fixed size bounding box around a tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/399758/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\DrawBoundingBox}[1][]{%
    \draw [
        %anchor=base,
        red,
    ]
    ([shift={(-5pt,-5pt)}]current bounding box.south west)
    rectangle
    ([shift={(5pt,+5pt)}]current bounding box.north east);
    
    %\useasboundingbox (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    
    \IfStrEq{#1}{}{}{% 5.0em selected to get failing test case
        \node [below, anchor=north, text width=5.0em, align=center, 
            %text depth=0pt,% 1. Bottom almost aligns (but slightly off), overlaps following text.
            %yshift=-\baselineskip,% 2. This along with applying a \smash, results in a single line text.
            baseline=0pt,
        ] 
            at (current bounding box.south)
            %{\smash{#1\strut}};%% Used with yshift=-\baselineskip option.
            {#1\strut};
    }%
}

\newcommand*{\MyRectangle}[1][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [fill=gray!20, draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
        \DrawBoundingBox[#1]
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand*{\MyCircle}[1][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [fill=yellow!20, draw=black] (0,0) circle (1.0cm);
        \DrawBoundingBox[#1]
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}
\section{No text}
    \MyCircle~%
    \MyRectangle%
    
    Some follow on text.

\section{Single line text}
    \MyCircle[Circle]~%
    \MyRectangle[Not Square]%
    
    Some follow on text.

\section{With multi line text}
    \MyCircle[Circle]~%
    \MyRectangle[Not quite a square]%
    
    Some follow on text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `baseline` option is usually a `tikzpicture` option but you can use it directly into your `tikzpicture` via `\tikzset`. Here, I define the `X` coordinate as the alignment point into your `\DrawBoundingBox` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand*{\DrawBoundingBox}[1][]{%
  \draw [red]
  ([shift={(-5pt,-5pt)}]current bounding box.south west)
  rectangle
  ([shift={(5pt,+5pt)}]current bounding box.north east);

  \coordinate (X) at (current bounding box.south);
  \tikzset{baseline={(X)}} % X is the alignment point

  \IfStrEq{#1}{}{}{% 5.0em selected to get failing test case
    \node [below, anchor=north, text width=5.0em, align=center, 
    ] 
    at (current bounding box.south)
    {#1\strut};
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\MyRectangle}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=gray!20, draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
    \DrawBoundingBox[#1]
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand*{\MyCircle}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=yellow!20, draw=black] (0,0) circle (1.0cm);
    \DrawBoundingBox[#1]
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}
\section{No text}
    \MyCircle~%
    \MyRectangle%

    Some follow on text.

\section{Single line text}
    \MyCircle[Circle]~%
    \MyRectangle[Not Square]%

    Some follow on text.

\section{With multi line text}
    \MyCircle[Circle]~%
    \MyRectangle[Not quite a square]%

    Some follow on text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good. I though that `baseline` was a `\node` option.

Comment: @PeterGrill There's a `base` `anchor` for nodes.

Comment: @cfr: Yeah, I think I got `baseline` and `base` mixed up.

Comment: Is `below` argument necessary ?

Comment: @Tarass The `below` option without argument is redundant with `anchor=north`.