# Why does rotating a circle alter its bounding box?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, size, bounding-box

Why does rotating a `tikzpicture` with a circle alter the height and width of the bounding box, and is there a way to not have this effect?

The MWE below yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\DrawBoundingBox}[1][]{%
    \draw [red]
    ([shift={(-5pt,-5pt)}]current bounding box.south west)
    rectangle
    ([shift={(5pt,+5pt)}]current bounding box.north east);

  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418499/
  %         align-tikzpictures-at-internal-bounding-box-with-text-below-it
  \coordinate (X) at (current bounding box.south);
  \tikzset{baseline={(X)}} % X is the alignment point

    \IfStrEq{#1}{}{}{%
        \node [below, anchor=north,  align=center,
            baseline=0pt, thin, shift only, solid,
        ]
            at (current bounding box.south)
            {#1\strut};
    }%
}

\newcommand*{\MyCircle}[2][]{%
    %% #1 = tikz picture options
    %% #2 = text
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [fill=yellow!20, draw=black, #1] (0,0) circle (1.0cm);
        \DrawBoundingBox[#2]
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}
\section{Height Changes}
\noindent
    \MyCircle[fill=green!25]{rotate=0}~%
    \MyCircle[fill=cyan!40, rotate=20]{rotate=20}~%
    \MyCircle[fill=orange!40, rotate=60]{rotate=60}%

\section{Width Changes}
\par\noindent\MyCircle[fill=green!25]{rotate=0}%
\par\noindent\MyCircle[fill=cyan!40, rotate=20]{rotate=20}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: The control points of the Bézier curves are taken into account and a circle is composed of [4 Bézier curves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734745/how-to-create-circle-with-b%c3%a9zier-curves).

Comment: @PaulGaborit PDF has has a low level circle command, no ? Why TikZ is using Bézier approximation here ?

Comment: @Kpym PDF does not provide a circle command...

Comment: @PaulGaborit really ? PS has `arc` command, and I thought that PDF has it too ... strange.

Comment: @Kpym Internally, the `arc` command uses Bézier curves (at least in ghostscript). ;-)

Comment: @PaulGaborit I know that the final rendering is often done in Bézier curves, but if we deffer this to the renderer we can treat it at higher level as arcs and circles (with the appropriate bounding box). In any case it looks strange to calculate the bounding box of a circle as if it is Bézier curve, even if we use them for rendering.

Comment: @PaulGaborit In any case the way TikZ calculate the bounding box of a Bézier curve (as convex envelope of the control points) is over simplistic ;)

Comment: @PaulGaborit: I'm curious, why are you providing the answer in the comments section? You have a very good answer posted below also.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit See [Why do people answer in comments?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3238/14500) (in the present case: too little time)

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Interesting. The equivalent meta post on other SE sites almost invariably declare that this is a terrible idea that violates the very purpose of the network, including explaining that "too little time" is an insufficiently strong reason to violate the SE model.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A circle is drawn by four Bézier curves. The control points of the Bézier curves are taken into account to compute the bounding box:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={midway, sloped, font=\tiny},
  decoration={show path construction,
    moveto code={},
    lineto code={},
    curveto code={
      \fill[red] (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) circle(.5pt);
      \fill[red] (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) circle(.5pt);
      \fill[blue] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) circle(.5pt);
      \fill[blue] (\tikzinputsegmentlast) circle(.5pt);
      \draw[blue,->] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta);
      \draw[blue,->] (\tikzinputsegmentlast) -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb);
      \draw [black] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
      (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
      ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast);
    },
    closepath code={},
  }]
  \draw [help lines] grid (6,3);
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=lbb]
    \path [decorate,rotate around={0:(1.5,1.5)}] (1.5,1.5) circle(1);
    \draw[red] (lbb.north west) rectangle (lbb.south east);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=lbb]
    \path [decorate,rotate around={30:(4.5,1.5)}] (4.5,1.5) circle(1);
    \draw[red] (lbb.north west) rectangle (lbb.south east);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Congratulations!! I was just looking up `show path constructions`.

Comment: Is it a bug, that Bézier control points are taken into account for the bounding box? If not, do you know the reason behind this decision?

Comment: @T.Verron It's not a bug (see p.124, pgfmanual, v3.0.1a)!  The reason is undoubtedly _efficiency_.  To work around this feature, you can try my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292373/14500) to question [tikz bounding box / cropping: too much space for curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290357/14500).

Comment: @PaulGaborit and Marmot congratulations for excellent code and Grill for excellent answer. +1

Answer (score 18):

I guess that you are using not the appropriate means to rotate the circles. If you use `transform canvas` instead, none of the issues arises. **UPDATE** I forgot to put `transform canvas` to the third circle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\DrawBoundingBox}[1][]{%
    \draw [red]
    ([shift={(-5pt,-5pt)}]current bounding box.south west)
    rectangle
    ([shift={(5pt,+5pt)}]current bounding box.north east);

  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418499/
  %         align-tikzpictures-at-internal-bounding-box-with-text-below-it
  \coordinate (X) at (current bounding box.south);
  \tikzset{baseline={(X)}} % X is the alignment point

    \IfStrEq{#1}{}{}{% 
        \node [below, anchor=north,  align=center, 
            baseline=0pt, thin, shift only, solid,
        ] 
            at (current bounding box.south)
            {#1\strut};
    }%
}

\newcommand*{\MyCircle}[2][]{%
    %% #1 = tikz picture options
    %% #2 = text
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [fill=yellow!20, draw=black, #1] (0,0) circle (1.0cm);
        \draw [#1] (-1,0) -- (1,0); % added to see that the transformatio does
                                    % something
        \DrawBoundingBox[#2]
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{No Height Changes}
\noindent
    \MyCircle[fill=green!25]{rotate=0}~%
    \MyCircle[fill=cyan!40, transform canvas={rotate=20}]{rotate=20}~%
    \MyCircle[fill=orange!40, transform canvas={rotate=60}]{rotate=60}%

\section{No Width Changes}
\par\noindent\MyCircle[fill=green!25]{rotate=0}%
\par\noindent\MyCircle[fill=cyan!40, transform canvas={rotate=20}]{rotate=20}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

(I added a line in order to show that this transformation does indeed rotate the circles, which is hard to see otherwise ;-)

Comment: So, what is the difference between `rotate=x` and `transform canvas={rotate=x}` and when would one want to use `rotate=x` instead of `transform canvas={rotate=x}`?

Comment: Also, it appears as if the heights _and_ widths are still not exactly the same.

Comment: Rotate=60 seems a little different, doesn't it?

Comment: @PeterGrill The height change is because I forgot to put `transform canvas` in the third circle.

Comment: Even the width does.

Comment: @Tarass now both do, I just forgot transform canvas there.

Comment: +1 people have been trying to square the circle a _long_ time.

Comment: `transform canvas` doesn't update the bounding box that's why. But usually other funny things happen if you don't use it carefully.