# Rotation of Tikz diagram makes the size variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, animate

I'm trying to animate a circle with some squares inside. I'd like the whole circle to rotate around its center. Somehow, the circle scaling is varing depending on the angle value. I've read a couple of posts and both animate and rotating manuals. Can someone please help me?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[autoplay,loop,nomouse]{animate}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newcommand{\obj}[1]{
\begin{turn}{#1}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale = 1]
%% Large circle
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=2.25in,very thick];
\node at (0,0) [rectangle,minimum size=1cm,fill=black,draw=black,shift={(3.5cm,3.5cm)},rotate=45] () {};
\node at (0,0) [rectangle, minimum size=.5cm,fill=black,draw=black,shift={(3cm,2cm)},rotate=25] () {};
\node at (0,0) [rectangle, minimum size=.25cm,fill=black,draw=black,shift={(1.75cm,1.5cm)},rotate=80] () {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{turn}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[controls]{72}%
\multiframe{72}{iAngle=0+5}{%
%iAngle = 80, 90, ..., 360 degrees
\obj{\iAngle}
}%
\end{animateinline}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a bit tricky because [rotating a circle changes the bounding box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426293/121799). So I added an explicit bounding box. And then you do not need the rotating package here, you can rotate with Ti*k*Z but need to add transform shape to get the desired effect.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[autoplay,loop,nomouse]{animate}

\newcommand{\obj}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
%% Large circle
\path[use as bounding box] (-2.5in,-2.5in) rectangle (2.5in,2.5in) ;
\begin{scope}[rotate=#1,transform shape]
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=2.25in,very thick];
\node at (3.5cm,3.5cm) [rectangle,minimum size=1cm,fill=black,draw=black,rotate=45] () {};
\node at (3cm,2cm) [rectangle, minimum size=.5cm,fill=black,draw=black,rotate=25] () {};
\node at (1.75cm,1.5cm) [rectangle, minimum size=.25cm,fill=black,draw=black,rotate=80] () {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[controls]{72}%
\multiframe{72}{iAngle=0+5}{%
%iAngle = 80, 90, ..., 360 degrees
\obj{\iAngle}
}%
\end{animateinline}%

\end{document}
```

The result

[image]

is obtained using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799), i.e. by adding `export` to the options of animate and then converting the multipage pdf to an animated gif.

In case you want only rotate the positions of the boxes, but not their orientation, try

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[autoplay,loop,nomouse]{animate}

\newcommand{\obj}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
%% Large circle
\path[use as bounding box] (-2.5in,-2.5in) rectangle (2.5in,2.5in) ;
\begin{scope}[rotate=#1]
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=2.25in,very thick];
\node at (3.5cm,3.5cm) [rectangle,minimum size=1cm,fill=black,draw=black,rotate=45] () {};
\node at (3cm,2cm) [rectangle, minimum size=.5cm,fill=black,draw=black,rotate=25] () {};
\node at (1.75cm,1.5cm) [rectangle, minimum size=.25cm,fill=black,draw=black,rotate=80] () {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[controls]{72}%
\multiframe{72}{iAngle=0+5}{%
%iAngle = 80, 90, ..., 360 degrees
\obj{\iAngle}
}%
\end{animateinline}%

\end{document}
```

[image]