# Why is the anchor=north west not working with a circle, but with a rectangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment

I want to place a circle in the corner of a gray background and this is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newlength{\width}
\setlength{\width}{16cm}
\newlength{\height}
\setlength{\height}{10cm}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=gray,minimum width=\width,minimum height=\height] at (0.5\width,0.5\height) {};


\draw[green] (0,0) |- (\width,\height);

\node[circle,anchor=north west,fill=blue,text=white,minimum size=0.2\height,font=\Large,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,\height) {T};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However the circle is not in the upper left corner as expected:
[image]

Now leave out the `circle` and try it again with:

```
\node[anchor=north west,fill=blue,text=white,minimum size=0.2\height,font=\Large,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,\height) {T};
```

And it works:
[image]

What am I doing wrong or what is going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well this is, because the `north west` anchor of the shape `circle`, which you are using to position the node, sits on the shape's border. As for the shape `rectangle`, the `north west` anchor also sits on the border of the shape but here it happens to coincide with the upper left corner of the shape's bounding box.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\Huge
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[name=s, shape=circle, line width=10pt, draw=black!15, fill=yellow!15, inner sep=1cm] {circle\vrule width 1pt height 2cm};
\edef\northwestanchor{north west}
\foreach \anchor/\placement in
    {north west/above left, north/above, north east/above right,
    west/left, center/above, east/right,
    mid west/right, mid/above, mid east/left,
    base west/left, base/below, base east/right,
    south west/below left, south/below, south east/below right,
    text/left, 10/right, 130/above} 
    \draw[shift=(s.\anchor), \ifx\anchor\northwestanchor red\fi] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)}
    node[\placement] {\scriptsize\texttt{(s.\anchor)}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can shift the node downwards and to the right since you know its height and width:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newlength{\width}
\setlength{\width}{16cm}
\newlength{\height}
\setlength{\height}{10cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=gray,minimum width=\width,minimum height=\height] at (0.5\width,0.5\height) {};

\draw[green] (0,0) |- (\width,\height);

\node[circle,shift={(0.1\height,-0.1\height)},fill=blue,text=white,minimum size=0.2\height,font=\Large,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,\height) {T};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

While [Jasper Habicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652953/16595) already explained the cause for your problem (`north west` lies on the border), for a more flexible solution you can define separate anchors, like I did in the code below for `corner north west`.

I took this from my [`positioning-plus`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/e55d95075e648b400b90e759522df4949af7c189/tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex#L37) library. Anchors for the other diagonals are defined there, too.

This is a general anchor, meaning every shape will be able to use it. Though, of course, for the more complex shapes, this will still not return the needed point.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newlength{\width} \setlength{\width}{16cm}
\newlength{\height}\setlength{\height}{10cm}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclaregenericanchor{corner north west}{%
  \pgf@sh@reanchor{#1}{north}%
  \pgf@ya\pgf@y
  \pgf@process{\pgf@sh@reanchor{#1}{west}}%
  \pgf@y\pgf@ya}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=gray,minimum width=\width,minimum height=\height] at (0.5\width,0.5\height) {};

\draw[green] (0,0) |- (\width,\height);
%                   ......
\node[circle,anchor=corner north west,fill=blue,text=white,
      minimum size=0.2\height,font=\Large,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,\height) {T};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you'd name the gray node, with the library, you could say `corner east below=0cm of <gray node>.north west`.

Answer (score 2):

This draws the circle first and positions everything else (background layer) relative to it.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}

\newlength{\width}
\setlength{\width}{16cm}
\newlength{\height}
\setlength{\height}{10cm}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill=blue,text=white,minimum size=0.2\height,font=\Large,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (T) {T};
\coordinate (origin) at ($(T.north -| T.west) + (0,-\height)$);

\begin{scope}[shift=(origin), on background layer]
  \node[fill=gray,minimum width=\width,minimum height=\height] at (0.5\width,0.5\height) {};

  \draw[green] (0,0) |- (\width,\height);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```