# TikZ/PGF draw algorithm

Tags: tikz-pgf, algorithms, draw

I have TikZ code that draws an ellipse. Here is the code that, AFAIK, draws the actual ellipse:

```
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},line width=0.8pt] (0.,0.) ellipse (5.cm and 4.cm);
```

Can anyone tell me how `draw` actually produces the line-work, i.e., is it behind-the-scenes using an interpolation algorithm to create coordinate points?

I've used *Geogebra* to generate TikZ code of a graph, and occasionally it simply brute-forces the shape of a line or object by generating tons of individual coordinates, making it rather unwieldy to put into a LaTeX document.

This, however, suggests to me the actual drawing of a shape with just a one-liner like above is some sort of interpolation, i.e. plotting per the ellipse formula a minimum base set of points, then interpolating the rest to fill in between them. I've read that this is typical, since using the ellipse formula to produce *all* of the points would be very resource and time expensive. Does anyone know what is going on under the hood?

Comment: If I recall correctly, one can not draw a "perfect" circle in a pdf. It is *interpolated* through spline curves and can be arbitrary precise (by increasing the number of splines). But one never gets a "perfect" circle/ellipse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[As JouleV points out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489545/121799), the ellipse is drawn in four Bezier curves. If you do not want to look these things up in the code, you can always use `show path construction` to see how the path is constructed.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={show path construction, % see p. 634 of the pgfmanual
    moveto code={
      \fill [red] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) circle (2pt)
        node [fill=none, below] {moveto};},
    lineto code={
      \draw [blue,->] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)
        node [above] {lineto};
    },
    curveto code={
      \draw [green!75!black,->] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast) node [above] {curveto};
    },
    closepath code={
      \draw [orange,->] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)
        node [above] {closepath};}
}]
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},line width=0.8pt,postaction=decorate] (0.,0.) ellipse (5.cm and 4.cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is also true for circles, which is why [rotating a circle can modify its bounding box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426285/121799).

Answer (score 8):

[`pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex), lines 892–1010:

```
% Append  an ellipse to the current path.
%
% #1 = center
% #2 = first axis
% #3 = second axis
%
% Example:
%
% % Add a circle of radius 3cm around the origin
% \pgfpathellipse{\pgforigin}{\pgfxy(2,0)}{\pgfxy(0,1)}
%
% % Draw a non-filled circle of radius 1cm around the point (1,1)
% \pgfpathellipse{\pgfxy(1,1)}{\pgfxy(1,1)}{\pgfxy(-2,2)}
% \pgfstroke

\def\pgfpathellipse#1#2#3{%
  \pgfpointtransformed{#1}% store center in xc/yc
  \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
  \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
  \pgfpointtransformed{#2}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x% store first axis in xa/ya
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
  \advance\pgf@xa by-\pgf@pt@x%
  \advance\pgf@ya by-\pgf@pt@y%
  \pgfpointtransformed{#3}%
  \pgf@xb=\pgf@x% store second axis in xb/yb
  \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
  \advance\pgf@xb by-\pgf@pt@x%
  \advance\pgf@yb by-\pgf@pt@y%
  {%
    \advance\pgf@xa by\pgf@xc%
    \advance\pgf@ya by\pgf@yc%
    \pgf@nlt@moveto{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}%
  }%
  \pgf@x=0.55228475\pgf@xb% first arc
  \pgf@y=0.55228475\pgf@yb%
  \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa%
  \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@ya%
  \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xc%
  \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yc%
  \edef\pgf@temp{\pgf@xc\the\pgf@x\pgf@yc\the\pgf@y}%
  \pgf@x=0.55228475\pgf@xa%
  \pgf@y=0.55228475\pgf@ya%
  \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xb%
  \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yb%
  {%
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xc%
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yc%
    \advance\pgf@xb by\pgf@xc%
    \advance\pgf@yb by\pgf@yc%
    \pgf@temp%
    \pgf@nlt@curveto{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}%
  }%
  \pgf@xa=-\pgf@xa% flip first axis
  \pgf@ya=-\pgf@ya%
  \pgf@x=0.55228475\pgf@xa% second arc
  \pgf@y=0.55228475\pgf@ya%
  \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xb%
  \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yb%
  \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xc%
  \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yc%
  \edef\pgf@temp{\pgf@xc\the\pgf@x\pgf@yc\the\pgf@y}%
  \pgf@x=0.55228475\pgf@xb%
  \pgf@y=0.55228475\pgf@yb%
  \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa%
  \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@ya%
  {%
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xc%
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yc%
    \advance\pgf@xa by\pgf@xc%
    \advance\pgf@ya by\pgf@yc%
    \pgf@temp%
    \pgf@nlt@curveto{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}%
  }%
  \pgf@xb=-\pgf@xb% flip second axis
  \pgf@yb=-\pgf@yb%
  \pgf@x=0.55228475\pgf@xb% third arc
  \pgf@y=0.55228475\pgf@yb%
  \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa%
  \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@ya%
  \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xc%
  \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yc%
  \edef\pgf@temp{\pgf@xc\the\pgf@x\pgf@yc\the\pgf@y}%
  \pgf@x=0.55228475\pgf@xa%
  \pgf@y=0.55228475\pgf@ya%
  \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xb%
  \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yb%
  {%
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xc%
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yc%
    \advance\pgf@xb by\pgf@xc%
    \advance\pgf@yb by\pgf@yc%
    \pgf@temp%
    \pgf@nlt@curveto{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}%
  }%
  \pgf@xa=-\pgf@xa% flip first axis once more
  \pgf@ya=-\pgf@ya%
  \pgf@x=0.55228475\pgf@xa% fourth arc
  \pgf@y=0.55228475\pgf@ya%
  \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xb%
  \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yb%
  \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xc%
  \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yc%
  \edef\pgf@temp{\pgf@xc\the\pgf@x\pgf@yc\the\pgf@y}%
  \pgf@x=0.55228475\pgf@xb%
  \pgf@y=0.55228475\pgf@yb%
  \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa%
  \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@ya%
  {%
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xc%
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yc%
    \advance\pgf@xa by\pgf@xc%
    \advance\pgf@ya by\pgf@yc%
    \pgf@temp%
    \pgf@nlt@curveto{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}%
  }%
  \pgf@nlt@closepath%
  \pgf@nlt@moveto{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}%
}
```

Well, just by reading the comments there you will know that the `ellipse` is drawn by four different curves (each curve is drawn with a `\pgf@nlt@curveto`).

Note that the same happens with `circle`.